# IIS hosted WCF web service config files

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm strugling to create a simple *IIS hosted WCF web service* and I'm having problems with config files.

As I understand Visual Studio should create `applicationhost.config` file in `\.vs\config\`, but there is no such folder. I'm using **Visual studio 2015¸Professional**.

I created new **WCF service** library project for this web service. Any idea or a hint where I went wrong?

Comment: You will be using the web.config when the service is hosted in IIS. Applicationhost.config is what controls IIS Express, it is not where you put your appSettings if that is what this is about.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new WCF service library project, Visual Studio should automatically create a web.config file in the project folder. This will be copied (and transformed if required) when building into the release/debug folder.